# В чем возможная ошибка?

Tags: php

```
if ($erro){
dbConnect();
mysql_query("insert into cart (******) values (******") or die (mysql_error);
}
?>
```

В браузере пишет просто mysql_error. В чем возможная ошибка?

Comment: Я смотрю, у вас низкий процент "принятых" вопросов... Вас ответы не устраивают, или вопросы задаете для развлекухи? Закрывать надо вопросы.

Answer (score 4):

```
or die (mysql_error())
```

mysql_error - функция.

Answer (score 1):

Не закрыл запрос к базе`

`mysql_query("insert into cart (***) values (***)") or die (mysql_error);`

Answer (score 1):

Объединяя оба ответа:

ошибка в запросе **values (***")**

поэтому запрос "умирает"

должен отработать ошибку, но и она с ошибкой написана, ибо "mysql_error - функция" (с)[[@Sh4dow](/users/465/sh4dow)](/users/465/sh4dow)

правильное написание:

mysql_query("insert into cart (******) values (******)") or die (mysql_error());

http://www.php.su/functions/?mysql-query